# Why is SSH blocked before first console login?

Tags: networking, ssh, authentication, debian, systemd

After booting a Debian/Buster virtual machine, the machine is not reachable via SSH. Waiting doesn't help.

However, right after the first login (no matter whether via console or Xorg), the SSH login is suddenly possible.

Which mechanism blocks the SSH login before the first console login?

How do I disable that mechanism?

Setup: I have a freshly installed Debian/Buster with installed SSH server whose network is configured directly via systemd-networkd.service.
However, using ifupdown+networking.service shows the same effect.

**Update**

Further investigation shows that it is sufficient to hit random keys at the console to make SSH starting up. No need to actually login via console. It seems to be solely about collecting entropy. However, making the system halt until there's entropy from the keyboard doesn't make sense on server and/or virtual machines.

So the question remains: How do I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question myself, I had to add a virtual random generator to the virtual machine. For example, in QEMU the following additional option is sufficient:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 ... -device virtio-rng-pci
```

Related documentation:

- https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/VirtIORNG

It still puzzles me why the above option is not the default.